# Template call static method

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I'm making a config library and would like to add the ability for users to make a class object configurable.
I want users to be able to run `configInstance.addOption<MyClass>()` and it run `MyClass::toConfig()`.

How would I implement this?

Comment: do you imply to pass some arguments into addOption method?

Comment: yes. like a default value, a std::string keyName, and a std::string comment

Comment: So, as far as you're using a template method, you're planning to use it with several classes. Therefore, each T class has to contain "keyName" and "comment" properties. Am I right? Otherwise, if MyClass is the only one that should be configured, I don't see any point to use templates.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
class Config
{
public:
    // ...

    template <typename T>
    void addOption()
    {
        T::toConfig();
    }

};
```

And then

```
Config configInstance;

configInstance.addOption<MyClass>();
```